# How to prove the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem in the Euclidean space.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ be a bounded infinite subset of $\mathbb{R}^l$. Then
>   it has a limit point.

So this is the Euclidean version of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, the thing is that I was trying to prove it by induction, but it doesn't help because in the case $l=1$ we constructed a sequence of intervals, such that each iteration has infinite number of points of the set, but what is the anlogy in $\mathbb{R}^l$?, Can someone help me to prove this please?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a sequence of hypercubes instead of intervals.

For example, taking $l=2$, lets assume (without loss of generality) that $A\subseteq [0,1]^2$.

Then, split $[0,1]^2$ into four subsquares (a square is a $2D$ cube):

$$A_{11} = [0,1/2]\times [0,1/2]\\
A_{12} = [1/2, 1]\times [0,1/2]\\
A_{21} = [0,1/2]\times [1/2, 1]\\
A_{22} = [1/2, 1]\times [1/2,1]$$

You know that one of the squares has infinitely many points. Pick that square and mark it $A_1$ and split it again.

In this way, you can construct a series of squares $$A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3\supseteq\cdots$$

And you can show that the intersection of these squares contains one point $x$. And that point must be a limit point of $A$, because it lies in $A_k$ and infinitely many other points also lie in $A_k$, so infinitely many points are at most $\frac{1}{2^k}$ away from $x$.

Comment: Ok let me check, If I get stuck, Can I let you know?, just give a while to think in your idea :)

Comment: @user162343 Of course. Anytime you have a question, drop a comment under this answer so I get a notification.

Answer (score 1):

The closure of $A$ is compact. In compact metric spaces each sequence has a convergent subsequence. If you may use that result you are done.

**Elaboration:** Since $A$ is infinite there is a injective sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq A$. Since $\overline{A}$ is compact $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $\overline{A}$. Since the limit is the limit of an injective sequence of elements of $A$ it is a limit point of $A$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more in this answer please?

Comment: @user162343 Do you mean how you get the limit point?

Comment: Well we need a candidate right?, and yes I want to show at least a limit point :) May be by construction or other means :)

Comment: @user162343 Better now?

Comment: Right :), the only thing I dont understand is the injective part :), how do you know it is injective?

Comment: @user162343 You simply pick the sequence injective. That's possible because $A$ is infinite.

Comment: aaaa right :), Now, some technical part, how do you know that the closure exists, because the closure is the union of $A$ and its limit points.

Comment: @user162343 In every topological space every subset has a closure. You can define it as the intersection of all closed supersets. Intersections of closed sets are closed again, so you immediately see that the so defined closure is closed and a superset.

Comment: I am sorry, I dont know topology :(, then how can I explain this?

Comment: A topological space is a generalization of a metric space. So everything what applies to all topological spaces will in particular be true for all metric spaces. So in your case just read "metric space".

Comment: What is a superset?, well the thing is that I haven't been I a topology course, so I cannot argue as is :( because it will be wrong

Comment: It's enough if you heard something about metric spaces and the properties of a compact metric space. If $A\supseteq B$ we say that $A$ is a superset of $B$.

Comment: Ok so can you state your answer, and your comment please in terms of only read analysis so I can understand what you want to say please :) thanks.

Comment: @user162343 My answer is only for people who know about compact metric spaces. If you are not familiar with such concepts better stick to other answers. But compact metric spaces should definitely be part of what you learn in your first year in Analysis.

Comment: Yes I know what a compact metric space is, the only thing is that in your answer, that I think is very clever, I have to argue that the closure exist or is not empty, but with the tools I have this is a little bit problematic because I need to ensure that the theorem is true before using the concept of closure, and that is what I want to know how to argue but only with simple machinery as is used in an ungraduate course :). I think it wont be a problem for you :).

Comment: @user162343 As I told you, by my (and also your) definition it is immediately clear that $\overline{A}$ exists and that we have $A\subseteq \overline{A}$. Since $A$ is infinite also $\overline{A}$ is infinite and therefore non-empty. But in my proof you don't need to show that $\overline{A}$ is non-empty. The statement of compact spaces also holds trivially for the empty compact space. So no need to consider this case at all. The theorem is still applicable.

Comment: Ok, so I can assume always that $\Abar$ because $A$ is infinite :), and by your answer we are done right?

Comment: @user162343 I don't understand your assumption.

Comment: @user162343 Sorry to say this, but if you do not know what a closure is, then you do *not* know compact metric spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Proving it for $l=1$ is enough to get the rest.

Let $X_n = (x_{1,n},\dots,x_{l,n})$ be an injective infinite sequence of points in the set $A$.

$x_{1,n}$ is bounded

So there is a subsequence s.t $x_{1,\phi_1(n)}$ converges

Now consider $X_{\phi_1(n)} = (x_{1,\phi_1(n)},\dots,x_{l,\phi_1(n)})$

$x_{2,\phi_1(n)}$ is bounded

So there is a subsequence s.t $x_{2,\phi_1\circ\phi_2(n)}$ converges

(Note that $x_{1,\phi_1\circ\phi_2(n)}$ also converges)

We repeat that until we find a subsequence that makes all the coordinates converge.

$(x_{1,\phi_1\circ\phi_2\dots\circ\phi_l(n)},\dots,x_{l,\phi_1\circ\phi_2\dots\circ\phi_l(n)})$ all converge, so $X_{\phi_1\circ\phi_2\dots\circ\phi_l(n)}$ also converges and its limit is a limit point of $A$

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying but who is the sequence $x_{2}$?

Comment: @user162343 $x_{1,n},\dots,x_{l,n}$ are the coordinates of $X_n$